# ¿Como recuperar las filas de un CURSOR FECTH de SqlServer en Visual Basic?

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb6

Un saludo a todos, he probado distintas formas de leer un CURSOR FECTH de SqlServer en Visual Basic, sin éxito; espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

**ASPX.VB (Código utilizado para leer el procedimiento almacenado)**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VALORES RETORNADOS POR EL CURSOR SQL SERVER**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

****Al realizar el Dubugger, sólo me retorna la primera fila****
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo recuperar todas las filas del cursor en visual basic?**. Gracias

Comment: El código va como texto

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré una solución, sólo es necesario utilizar un dataSet para obtener el conjunto de valores del CURSOR FETCH.

**Código Visual Basic (ASPX.VB)**

```
Dim DatosDevueltos As DataSet

Adaptador = New SqlDataAdapter
DatosDevueltos = New DataSet

Adaptador.SelectCommand = Cmd
Adaptador.Fill(DatosDevueltos)

Return DatosDevueltos
```

*Gracias a todos por su apoyo*